# How to select substring on entity column using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an entity called `Note` which has an attribute `text`, and I implemented a `JpaRepository` as follow:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String text;
}

public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, Long> {
}
```

in my view I want to show just a chunk of the column text, in SQL it would be `substr(text, 1, 200)`, I could use java substring but I'd like to retrieve the text from database already chunked and inject the result into the `Note.text` attribute, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`substring` is a standard function of JPQL (See the [Hibernate ORM documentation about functions][1]). This query will work:

```
select n.id, n.title, substring(n.text, 1, 200) as text from Note n
```

The problem is that Spring doesn't recognize that the fields are part of of the entity and won't transform the result automatically.

You can fix this issue adding a constructor to Note:

```
public Note(Long id, String title, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
}
```

And now you can have:

```
@Query("select new Note(n.id as id, n.title as title, substring(n.text, 1, 200)) from Note n")
List<Note> findListWithShortenedText();
```

If you don't want the constructor, this will work:

```
@Query("select n.id as id, n.title as title, substring(n.text, 1, 200) from Note n")
List<Object[]> findNotesWithShortenedText();
```

And you can read the value this way:

```
List<Object[]> results = repository.findListWithSHortenedText();
for(Object[] row : results) {
    Long id = (Long) row[0];
    String title = (String) row[1];
    String text = (String) row[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried and got this exception ```org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.testenotas.testenotes.Note]```

Comment: Did you use the exact query in my answer?

Comment: Are you using JPA 2.0? Which database are you using?

Comment: Ah... you are right, sorry. It returns a `List<Object[]>`. I will update the answer.

Comment: I've updated my asnwer